# Inverse Laplace transform only returning exponentials

Tags: trigonometry, integral-transforms

The inverse Laplace transform is only returning exponentials. I know it is from the definition
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma - i\infty}^{\gamma + i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds = \sum\text{Res}
$$
However, I would like to have the results returned as cosine and sine functions. I tried FullSimplify and TrigReduce but this does nothing. Is there anyway to force Mathematica to return trig functions?

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(
 12*183.26)/((s^2 + 183.26^2) (55*s^2 + (
    5.5*s^2 (s*24.2525 + 784.243))/(5.5*s^2 + 24.2525*s + 784.243) + 
    8000)), s, t]
```

Comment: Have you tried `ExpToTrig`?

Comment: Try using the [`ExpToTrig`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpToTrig.html) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lap = InverseLaplaceTransform[(12*183.26)/((s^2 + 183.26^2) (55* s^2 + (5.5*s^2 (s*24.2525 + 784.243))/
               (5.5*s^2 + 24.2525*s + 784.243) + 8000)), s, t];

{re, im} = (Simplify[#@lap, Assumptions -> t ∈ Reals] // ComplexExpand // Chop) & /@ {Re, Im};

re
(* 

 0.0000328276 E^(-0.675566 t) Cos[10.5332 t] - 
 0.0000164059 E^(-1.74968 t) Cos[13.5317 t] - 
 0.0000164059 E^(-1.74968 t) Cos[13.5317 t] - 
 1.59052*10^-8 Cos[183.26 t] + 
 0.0000551514 E^(-0.675566 t) Sin[10.5332 t] + 
 0.0000214317 E^(-1.74968 t) Sin[13.5317 t] + 
 0.0000214317 E^(-1.74968 t) Sin[13.5317 t] - 
 6.52719*10^-6 Sin[183.26 t]

*)
```

The imaginary part is of course negligible

Edit: One step more:

```
p = (Plus @@@  Gather[List @@ re, (List @@ Last[List @@ (#1)] == 
                                   List @@ Last[List @@ (#2)] &)]) /. 
                                    f_[a_ t] :> f[Round[a, .0000001] t]

Plus @@ (FullSimplify /@ p)

(*

-1.59052*10^-8 Cos[183.26 t] + 
 E^(-0.675566 t) (0.0000328276 Cos[10.5332 t] + 0.0000551514 Sin[10.5332 t]) + 
 E^(-1.74968 t) (-0.0000328117 Cos[13.5317 t] + 0.0000428634 Sin[13.5317 t]) -    
 6.52719*10^-6 Sin[183.26 t]
*)
```